# How to add bottom panel in wp-customize (WordPress)?

Tags: php, wordpress

How to add bottom panel in wp-customize (WordPress) ?

[image]

This is Blocksy theme.

[image]

Or like Astra theme, you can use the bottom control panel to use the Gutenberg editor?

If I want to develop a theme, how can I achieve such functionality?

How was the control panel at the bottom created?

thank you.